# NEMA 6-50 plug to attach to electrical conduit

Tags: wiring

I bought a EVSE with pigtail leads because it had strong conduit around the supply cables to protect them from damage. However now I go to get ready to install the EVSE and I can't seem to find a NEMA 6-50 plug that accepts the below threaded conduit end into the plug's rear end. I understand conduit has many options to terminate it into a box, but surely there is some need to have the cable protected by conduit up to plugs, no?

[image]

Comment: Plug ends are made for cordage, not conduit, and your EVSE's pigtail is made to screw into a junction box and be hardwired there.  Do you need a cord-and-plug connection?  If you're okay with hardwiring instead, that would be fairly easy.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Flexible conduit is permanent wiring.  Cords are temporary wiring. Cords are made to flex daily. Conduit is not.  There are no plugs for permanent wiring, for this reason.  How do you want to connect this?  Permanent wiring, or a flexible cord?

Comment: @Nate S - Reinstate Monica - With respect, wouldn't be asking if I wanted to put the conduit into a junction box. Want the cord to be conduit protected right up until the plug, which will be underneath a locked outdoor socket housing.

Comment: Well, to answer your last sentence more directly, no, there is not generally a need for conduit to protect cords up to the plug.  Have you ever even seen such an arrangement?  I haven't.  And as Harper explains below, conduit is not meant for that.

Comment: Have you considered getting a different EVSE?

Comment: @Nate S - Reinstate Monica - The need is those who are anti-EV having an easier job cutting cables to prevent charging. Regardless of whether I have seen this before, does not mean it doesn't exist or shouldn't exist.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I had the choice to get a flexible cord, fitted with plug, with no conduit protection around it. As explained above, I chose this version for a reason.

Comment: Edit your question to include the requirements you've stated in comments.

Comment: @user66001 -- what trade size is this flexible conduit?  Also, are you open to types of plugs other than standard NEMA straight blade?  (What you're after isn't completely unheardof in industrial work, but those applications don't use straight-blade NEMA configs for this, instead using locking-type or pin-and-sleeve plugs and receptacles)

Comment: @user66001 If the goal here is anti-vandal, you don't want a plug anyway. Even if you get it exactly the way you think you want, they will sabotage it **simply by unplugging it**, and then, you won't get to work tomorrow.  It's unclear to me why you are so opposed to hardwiring, it's really no big deal. And much more vandal resistant because it makes it impossible for them to vandalize without touching hot wires.

Comment: @user66001, yes, as Harper points out, vandals could just as easily (easier actually, since there's no risk of shock to them) unplug it and vandalize the plug and/or socket (i.e. snapping off the prongs, filling the socket with dirt or glue, etc.).  Conduit really doesn't buy you anything if you insist on keeping the plug accessible.

Comment: @user66001, one more thought, isn't the cord from EVSE to vehicle regular cordage that is just as easily vandalized?  I don't think there's a way to avoid the vandalism risk while the charger is in use (though perhaps a security camera could discourage it).  OTOH, to protect it while it's not in use, you could mount the whole thing, outlet and all, inside a locking cabinet.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - 1" is the flexible conduit size. I would prefer to keep with consumer standard plug types, so that the next owner can use the plug without changing it or getting an adaptor that will be cumbersome and perhaps not sit under the waterproof hood.

Comment: @Harper - I trust you have heard of covers for outdoor boxes which can be padlocked. I had no idea when I wrote asking for a plug to attach to this conduit I would need to detail the whole plan to allow another owner of the house to use the plug when I took my charger with me, keeping it relatively safe from vandals, and bunch of other considerations. P.S I have a 310 mile range in my E.V. and a 30 mile commute. If I needed to I could go almost 2 weeks without charging. Besides, where I live there is literally hundreds of Level 2 charging...

Comment: ...let alone all those I know in the area who all have 110V AC (and everyone else that I don't has this to), which can easily recover 30 miles overnight. As to the resistance of hard-wiring, I simply want to unplug the charger when I leave, and not have the hassle of switching of the breaker, pulling apart the junction box, wiring in a plug, testing, then switching back on the breaker. I guess you haven't also considered the possibility of the charger, an electronic device, failing one day and then me having to the above in the dark instead of just using the portable charger my car came with.

Comment: @user66001 how much current does this EVSE actually draw?

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica - In regards to your agreeance with Harper, please see my first comment to this person directly above. In regards to the cord from the charger to the car, this is already housed in heavy duty conduit (aftermarket). This segway is interesting, but doesn't address the question. I have already well thought out the subject of protection for the cabling, box, etc, bar finding a solution to keep the wires in the existing conduit through to the locked cover junction box.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - The EVSE is capable of drawing 40A through it, though my current EV is limited to drawing 32A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is possible, but *only* if you ditch NEMA 6-50, and you'll need a written Code variance for it due to EVSE-specific requirements

The use of a plug on the end of a flexible conduit whip is not unprecedented; some industrial and hazardous location applications require the extra protection conduit provides, or unusual conductor configurations that don't correspond to stock cordage, and thus use plugs attached to the end of flexible conduit whips or pendants instead.  However, you can't do this with any old garden-variety plug; a special adapter is necessary, and that adapter *won't fit* on standard plugs as it replaces the plug's *cord grip*, which is an integral part of the housing on standard plugs.

Furthermore, while *locking* 50A plugs are available with adapters to convert them to conduit whip usage, NEC 625.44 prohibits the use of locking plugs for connecting EVSE to building electrical systems, presumably due to issues with forces on the EVSE during a forcible decoupling incident (IOW: someone trying to drive off with the car still plugged into the charger).  This would normally force us to go with *pin and sleeve* type plugs and receptacles; these are standard worldwide and in US industrial work for high power applications, and have flexible conduit adapters available as a result, but are not used domestically *at all* in North America.  However, there aren't any 50A pin-and-sleeve configurations, either; your choices are either the 30/32A configuration, or the 60/63A configuration, and the latter's no good as 625.44 also limits the plug size of a non-hard-wired stationary EVSE to 50A.

So, I'd explain your concerns to the local electrical inspector, and see if they'll grant you a variance to use either a 50A locking plug or a 60/63A pin-and-sleeve plug on your EVSE, provided you use the correct conduit adapter for the plug you are using.  Note that either way, you'll be quite limited as to where you can plug this in compared to standard NEMA 6-50 or 14-50 plugs, but those, as I said earlier, won't fit on flexible conduit at all, and it's quite unwise to try, either, as the strain relief just won't work out the way you want it to.

Comment: It seems strange that NEC would prohibit locking plugs but allow hardwiring if the concern is forceful removal.  Plus, I thought the vehicle end of most EVSE plugs was designed to decouple in that case.

Comment: Superlative answer.  Pure Code genius.  Possibly uneconomical, but OP has *particular* requirements and cannot possibly expect "particular" to be "cheap".

Comment: @Harper -- note that I'm assuming the EVSE is >30A by the OP's use of a NEMA 6-50 plug.  If it's <30A, then a 30A/32A pin-and-socket plug can be used, and it'll be completely Code, no variances needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ThreePhaseEel. The first one that actually provides solutions along the lines of the questions, rather than suggesting something I can already do and have reasons not to. However, isn't NEMA 6-__50__ 50A max capable. I do believe there is a 6-__30__ that maxes out at 30A.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica - Wonder whether the NEC rules apply to fixed chargers, or portable ones, but all electric vehicles (bar Tesla, but they prevent the vehicle being put into drive with a charging cable still attached) I am aware of have the plugin to the car end able to be pulled out relatively easy.

Answer (score 4):

OK, another swing at this given that you *also* want the NEMA 6-50 plug to be available to use with a portable charger if the main fails.

### The cheaty way

I'll use a precedent here.  They make little [subpanels meant to go at RV parking spots](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-RV-Panel-with-50-Amp-and-30-AMP-RV-Receptacles-and-a-20-Amp-GFCI-Receptacle-GE1LU532SS/203393689), which include all relevant sockets.  Different RVs require different plugs, so they supply NEMA 14-50, NEMA 14-30 and NEMA 5-20 at the same time. They are allowed to be fed by a single 50A supply breaker, even though if all 3 kinds of RVs plugged in, they could pull 100A.  *Why is this allowed?* **Because only one RV will fit on an RV stand.** If the 14-50 is in use, the 14-30 must not be.

So.  Hardwire it like I suggest, but instead of a blank cover plate on the panel, fit a NEMA 6-50 *and hook it up so both the hardwire and 6-50 are live*.  Label the 6-50 socket "EVSE Only". It can't be used unless your hardwired charger is not in use.  Because it's only one parking space.

### The non-cheaty way

Install *exactly* one of those RV subpanels that has at least 4 breaker spaces.  Change one of the panel front sockets to NEMA 6-50, and add an extra 50A breaker to feed the EVSE charger that you hardwire.  If it has a 5th breaker space, then support the NEMA 5-20 outlet also, giving  you another way to plug in.

If you really, really want the existing charger to plug in, then do hardwire it into the panel, but wire it to a flexible cord and have it exit the panel and loop right back into the panel  Noting that these panels have outdoor in-use covers, that can be locked, have the cord's starting point be somewhere protected.

---

---

Based on what you say in comments, your primary concern is armoring the installation against casual vandalism, e.g. cable cutting. Presumably our vandal is bright enough to de-energize a cord before cutting it, so he'd unplug a flexible cable before cutting, eh?

### Use a *permanent wiring method* ... temporarily

In other words, overcome your reluctance to hard-wire, because hard-wiring is really the right way to do this.

I have the experience to hardwire a thing like this in about 2 minutes.  For me, it's not any harder than wiring a plug.  I do all sorts of temporary work, and it's perfectly routine for me to "permanently" wire something up, all spit-shined and inspection-ready... then, 4 hours later, "permanently" unwire it.

That's exactly what you should do. Bap in a knockout on the junction box, and wire it in that way; either cap off the receptacle's wires or replace the receptacle with a 50 cent blank cover plate.  If the box is mounted flush, then add an extension box and side-enter that, or get a blank plate with a knockout hole on its face. Depending on what works physically at the site.

And then, when you move, just unhook the wires and cap it off with a 20 cent knockout plug, in a neat and proper manner.  Done.  It's really no different than removing a chandelier.

*It goes without saying that you turn off the supply circuit breaker before touching the circuit wiring*. Also, NEC requires that EVSEs are dedicated circuits, and forbids multiple outlets on 50A circuits with a socket, so de-energizing this circuit won't affect other users.*

### Why that thing is not available

The concept of a "plug" implies there is a cord attached to it *which is rated as **cordage**, i.e. is made for frequent flexing*.  Flexible conduit is not rated for frequent flexing; it is intended for fixed, permanent installation and its bendiness is only intended as a convenience to the installer.  As such, a plug for flexible conduit *is a contradiction in terms*.

At least in the consumer space.  ThreePhaseEel describes some industrial exotica, but it'll be industrial-priced, and *still* need a variance from the AHJ to use it.

You say "It's mere coincidence that nobody makes it" - no, it's not.  You may notice that every piece of electrical equipment (such as a plug) has a stamp that says UL, CSA, ETL or other marks (CE is not one).  These are Nationally Recognized Testing Labs (NRTL).  NEC 110.2 requires that every piece of equipment be "approved". The instructions must be approved as part of the listing.  **UL won't approve instructions that tell the user to violate NEC**.  So the maker would need to find a use for this thing that does not violate NEC, get their UL listing based on *those* instructions, and then you would use the device *contrary to its instructions*, which violates NEC 110.3b.

So it isn't happenstance that these don't exist.  There's reason for them not to.

### Or, hardwire to one box, and jumper to the other

However this won't work if your risk is vandalism.

Go to a real electrical supply house.  Get a NEMA 6-50P line cord with pre-molded plug, that uses proper *cordage*.  Also get the correct strain relief that fits that particular cordage ... *and that's why I'm sending you to the electrical supply.*

Now get a 4-11/16" or 4" deep junction box.  Fit the 6-50 cord and strain relief into one of its knockouts.  Then screw it to the wall within cord's reach of your NEMA 6-50 socket and within reach of that flexible conduit.

Put this EVSE's flexible conduit into another knockout.

Pigtail a #10 ground wire off the ground screw on the box,  then splice wires to match.

*Voilà*, now you can plug and unplug the EVSE at will, you are not flexing things not meant to flex, you are flexing things meant to flex, and it's Code legal.NEC 400.7(A)(6).

> **400.7 Uses Permitted.**
>
> (A) Uses. Flexible cords and cables shall be used only for the following:
>
> - (6) Connection of utilization equipment *(that's any device which uses electricity for something)* to facilitate *(allow)* frequent interchange.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear on the reason for getting the EVSE configured with pigtail leads within conduit. I want the entire run from EVSE to 6-50 socket protected from damage that flexible cords are very susceptible to. Alas you are making an assumption that I want to unplug and plug the 6-50 plug and socket often. In fact I just want it this way so I can take my EVSE with me and the 240v supply to the outside of the house will have a socket someone else can use when we move (which may be in 5 years or more). Doing as you suggest won't achieve this.

Comment: @user66001, it sounds like this is an XY problem -- you don't need to connect a plug end to a conduit (you can't); rather, you need to find a way to protect an outdoor cord from physical damage -- there are other ways to achieve that.

Comment: @Nate S - Reinstate Monica - You can't simply because no-one makes something to do so, not because it is impossible. Could I suggest that instead of pointing out that there is an alternative, examples of that alternative are provided?

Comment: Note that while it's possible to get locking or pin-and-sleeve plugs that can be fitted to flexible conduit whips, it appears that using such a plug for an EVSE's mains input is a no-no in Code (625.44 requires a non-locking type plug...)

Comment: @user66001, I didn't write up another alternative answer because I was pretty sure you'd just reject it for not meeting your requirements.  My recommendation would be the same as Harper's latest edit, and Ecnerwal's answer -- just hardwire it.  It's not hard to undo when you move, and it's the safest method.  I have no idea why you're so against it.

Comment: There miiight be another possible solution if your EVSE has a knockout (or space to make one) for a very large conduit (big enough that you could fit the whole cord with plug down it).  Does it?

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica - If this alternative answer is to hard wire it, or doesn't provide a way to put a plug on the end of the conduit to not be unplugged (hopefully) for years and years, then you are correct, this doesn't address the question posed and wouldn't be worth providing to me. I have address why I am against it in others questions, but to repeat, when I move it isn't a simple matter of unplugging the plug, I have to switch off the mains, source a socket, install it, test it, and reconnect the mains. When we move this is not something I would like to add to the long list of things

Comment: ... needing to be done. There is also the possibility that the charger will fail, as is a chance of every electrical device, and with a socket I can simply unplug the fixed charger and use the portable charger that came with the car, rather than messing around potentially in the dark to provide power to my car to charge overnight. The conduit pictured (1") comes from a large knockout on the EVSE. While I would prefer not, I could always open up the EVSE and wire a cord feed through from the loose end with plug attached, but then have the issue of the conduit being mated to the NEMA socket box

Comment: ... which I have not seen a way to do either.

Comment: @Harper I will accept you have a point about the requirement to have your electrical connection, device, etc "approved", which is clearly the reason a solution doesn't exist, but for those who won't see my comments further above, I trust you have heard of outdoor boxes which can be padlocked, so the vandal can't just unplug the cable, eh? The idea to use cordage from one junction box to allow unplugging the EVSE is a lot more equipment than just a non-available plug for conduit for a installation that may the plug unplugged ONCE in YEARS (so the argument that conduit isn't supposed to bend is

Comment: ...nullified. As for the other reason I want a socket is should the charger fail one night, I don't want to be pissing around with installing a socket so that the portable charger included with the car can be plugged in to charge it in the interim while I repair/replace the EVSE. As mentioned to another commentor, didn't see the need to detail all considerations or plans for this project when asking about a plug for the end of conduit. It doesn't exist because it wouldn't be code, and their is a requirement for things to conform to code, would have been a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the plug, hardwire it into a junction box as intended, switch off the breaker if you want it "unplugged."

Whole run protected by conduit - done.

Not violating electrical code and common sense - done.

When you move and want to take it with you, switch off the breaker and disconnect the wires, putting a blank conduit hole cover in the junction box where you remove the conduit. You don't need a receptacle and plug for that. If you want to leave a receptacle there, put that in instead of a blank conduit hole cover, at that time.

Comment: Not answering the question, could have done this "default" choice hours ago without as much hassle commenting to multiple people who wanted to essentially state what I want to use conduit for is not what conduit is used for and I should do what they think is logical,  and just had stick in "common sense" (a.k.a stop being so stupid). Why did I post for help again?

Comment: For others who come across this answer, need to also state that one of the other reasons that I would not have imagined I needed to detail when asking for a __plug__ that goes on the end of conduit, and not to be told to just go a bloody well hardwire it you idiot, is that should the EVSE fail, I don't want to be pissing around with installing a socket probably at night to charge my vehicle overnight (no, not because it has a low range - 310 is in fact how far it can travel of a full battery, but because I work full time and come home after dark 5 days a week). With a socket installed I can...

Comment: ... just pull out the portable charger from my trunk and plug it in and work on fixing/replacing the broken EVSE one my own schedule. Common sense for those who own electric vehicles!